# Webservice and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have a website with webservice active(prestashop)
This site require an authentication.

I use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36";
request.Method = "GET";            
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("key", "");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
//request.Connection
request.Host = "localhost";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
String R = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The code is ok but my problem is that there is a login form for the webservice

In fact, the HttpWebRequest object , sends two requests: 
with the first answer is not authorized while the second was ok status.

I used fiddler web debbuger.
I apologize for my English.

Comment: FYI, your `WebResponse`, `Stream` and `StreamReader` should be in `using` blocks to ensure they are cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

if the form is submitted using GET method you must pass the form paramaters in the url query string, for instance `http://url?username={0}&pass={1}`. If it is POST method, you must pass the form info into the http body request. There is a lot of examples in stackoverflow of this. Also you must handle the cookies witch is achieve using the CookieContainer. In the first request intialize the container

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

when the request comeback with ok status the cookies will be in `request.Cookies` witch is a CookieCollection instance. Later for further request you must have to pass this cookies in order to retrieve the correct data.

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(userCookies);
```

Hope it helps!